# Ошибки в справке и не только

Tags: статус-завершено, дефект, предложение

Предлагаю исправить:

1. https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour

   - "Русский язык — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка". Этимологи не лингвисты что ли? Это как "сайт для людей и депутатов". Запятая перед *и* не нужна. Вообще, я предлагаю такую аннотацию: *"Русский язык" – это сайт вопросов и ответов для всех, кому интересен русский язык*.
   - Там же "С вами вместе мы создаем библиотеку подробных ответов на любой вопрос по русскому языку" предлагаю заменить на *"Вместе мы создаем библиотеку подробных ответов на вопросы о русском языке"*.
   - "Мы немного отличаемся от других сайтов. Вот наши отличия:" на *Мы немного отличаемся от других сайтов:*
   - "Принятие ответа не означает, что этот ответ лучший; это значит, что изложенное в нём решение сработало для автора вопроса" на *Принятие ответа не означает, что он лучший; это значит, что изложенное в нём решение помогло автору вопроса*.
   - "Наша цель — собрать лучшие ответы на все вопросы, поэтому если вам попадутся вопросы или ответы, требующие улучшения, вы можете отредактировать их" на *Наша цель — собрать лучшие ответы на все вопросы, поэтому, если вам попадутся сообщения, требующие улучшения, вы можете отредактировать их.*
   - "Используйте Комментарии, чтобы получить дополнительную информацию или уточнить вопрос или ответ" на *Используйте комментарии, чтобы получить дополнительную информацию или уточнить вопрос или ответ*.
2. https://rus.stackexchange.com/help

   - "Только присоединились к Русский язык? Совершите тур, чтобы узнать всё, что необходимо для начала работы" на *Вы здесь в первый раз? Совершите тур, чтобы узнать всё необходимое для начала работы*.
3. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

   - > Как Задавать Вопросы
     >
     > Is your question about русский язык?
     >
     > We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
     >
     > Provide details. Share your research.
     >
     > If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

   на

> Как задавать вопросы
>
> - Вопрос должен быть о русском языке.
> - Вопрос должен быть конкретным (чтобы на него можно было дать лаконичный ответ).
> - Указывайте детали.
> - Если у вас есть свои соображения, опишите их.
> - Если у вас есть предложения по улучшению сайта, опишите их на [Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/).

- "visit the help center »
  asking help »" на *посетить справочный центр / как задать хороший вопрос?*
- > Основы Форматирования
  >
  > ► ставьте перевод строки между абзацами
  >
  > ► для переноса строки завершите предыдущую 2 пробелами
  >
  > ► *курсив* или **жирный**
  >
  > ► для создания цитаты введите > в начале строки
  >
  > ► чтобы добавить ссылки
  >
  > http://foo.com [foo](http://foo.com) foo
  >
  > ► также можно использовать базовый HTML

на

> Основы форматирования
>
> - Ставьте перевод строки (клавиша "Enter") между абзацами.
> - Чтобы начать с новой строки, завершите предыдущую двумя пробелами.
> - Чтобы выделить текст *курсивом* или **жирным**, поставьте по краям * или ** соответственно. ***Жирный курсив*** – *** по краям.
> - Чтобы сделать цитату, введите> в начале строки.
> - Чтобы добавить ссылки, используйте (нужна ли это тягомотина? я предлагаю убрать этот пункт вообще)
>
> http://foo.com [foo](http://foo.com) foo
>
> - Вы можете использовать базовый HTML.
> - Перечисленные выше функции также доступны на панели команд.

- > Руководство По Использованию Меток
  >
  > Метка — это ключевое слово, которое используется для поиска похожих
  >   вопросов и их классификации.
  >
  > ► используйте существующие популярные метки; старайтесь не создавать
  >   новых
  >
  > ► используйте распространённые аббревиатуры
  >
  > ► не употребляйте синонимы
  >
  > ► объединяйте несколько слов в одно слово с помощью дефисов (если
  >   возможно)
  >
  > ► не более 5 меток, 25 символов в каждой
  >
  > ► допустимые символы: a-z, а-я, 0-9, + - . #
  >
  > ► разделяйте метки с помощью пробела, запятой или точки с запятой

на

> Руководство по использованию меток
>
> Метка — это ключевое слово, которое используется для поиска похожих
>   вопросов и их классификации.
>
> - Используйте существующие популярные метки; старайтесь не создавать
>     новых.
> - Используйте распространённые аббревиатуры.
> - Не употребляйте синонимы.
> - Объединяйте несколько слов в одно с помощью дефисов (если
>     возможно). Например: *употребление-слов*.
> - Для каждого вопроса возможно не более 5 меток (максимально 25 символов в каждой).
> - Допустимые символы: a-z, а-я, 0-9, + - . #.
> - Разделяйте метки с помощью пробела, запятой или точки с запятой.

4. https://rus.stackexchange.com/review

   - > Помогите Улучшить Сайт
     >
     > Русский язык модерируется вами.
     >
     > Помогите другим участникам освоиться на сайте и повысить качество
     >   вопросов и ответов:
     >
     > Оценивайте новые сообщения Голосуйте за закрытие или повторное
     >   открытие вопросов Проверяйте предложенные правки Выберите задачу
     >   слева, чтобы начать работу.

на

> Помогите улучшить сайт
>
> "Русский язык" модерируется вами.
>
> Помогите другим участникам освоиться на сайте и повысить качество
>   вопросов и ответов:
>
> - Оценивайте новые сообщения.
> - Голосуйте за закрытие или повторное открытие вопросов.
> - Проверяйте предложенные правки.
>     (Тут пропущенная строка, редактор глючит.)
>     Выберите задачу слева, чтобы начать работу.

Comment: Это далеко не все замеченные ошибки, но для начала хотя бы это исправить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky что думаете об этом?

Comment: Огромное спасибо за замечания! Постараюсь в ближайшее время исправить. П.С. К сожалению, упоминания работают лишь в том случае, если участник, которого вы упоминаете, уже принимал участие в вопросе.

Comment: "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed." и "Вопрос должен быть конкретным (чтобы на него можно было дать лаконичный ответ)" достаточно разные вещи, а требование *лаконичного* ответа - вообще левая самодеятельность

Comment: @LazyBadger давайте свой вариант или обоснование.

Comment: Прямой перевод "Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно ответить, а не только их обсудить". Типа в натуре патамушта на некоторые чиста канкретные вопросы я отвечу конкретно и определенно, но вот лаконичности там не будет. Мой ответ на простой вопрос "Реформа орфографии 18 года - добро или зло?" потянул более 2000 знаков, к примеру. И это - lazy style, без цитат и списков библиогафии. А вот вопрос "англизация современного русского языка - это OK или не OK" - чисто флудогенератор с ненулевой суммой, но без definitive answer, к примеру. Ферштейн?

Comment: Кто там против калек выступал? Хм... А вопросы типа ваших (реформа орфографии: ок / не ок и под.) не соответствуют тематике сайта. Ich verstehe dich nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за отзыв! Действительно, досадные ошибки.

---

- Страница Тура. Поправил следующим образом.

  > Русский язык — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов, этимологов и энтузиастов русского языка. Он создан и управляется вами, являясь частью сети Stack Exchange. С вами вместе мы создаем библиотеку подробных ответов на любые вопросы о русском языке.

  Фраза «*для всех, кому интересен русский язык*» не используется, так как сайт для профессионалов и энтузиастов, то есть, вероятно, все–таки не совсем для всех.

  > Мы немного отличаемся от других сайтов:

  Это строка с Transifex. Поправил, в ближайшее время будет на сайте.

  > Принятие ответа не означает, что этот ответ лучший...

  Пожалуйста, обсудите эту правку с alexolut. Он уже правил эту строку. Возможно у него есть какие–то другие соображения, которые следует учесть.

  > Наша цель — собрать лучшие ответы на все вопросы...

  Поправил.

  > Используйте Комментарии...

  Поправил.
- Баннер для нового участника.

  > Только присоединились...

  Готово.

Остальные ошибки в процессе. Как только исправим, обновлю ответ.

Comment: Замечательно! Тогда в Туре нужно убрать *этимологов*, это никуда не годиться. Сохранение *этот ответ лучший* можно понять, но вот *сработал для* в любом случае, что называется, не по-русски, см. словарь: *Произвести нужное действие (**о машине, механизме**)*. // Продолжать поиск?

Comment: Ах да, еще: все-таки ***с вами** вместе* избыточно: из контекста понятно, кто с кем вместе. Более того, ранее уже употреблялось *вами*, поэтому фраза в нынешнем виде тавтологична.

Comment: @Aer Описание поправил. Фразу «этот ответ лучший...» поправил, и оставил соответствующий комментарий на Transifex.

Comment: @Aer Опечатки в боковой панели уберем за счет переноса строк с Stack Overflow на русском. В процессе.

Comment: Вижу, что перенос завершен. Но вот заголовки неправильно везде написаны. Только первое слово должно быть с прописной: Как создавать вопросы, Статистика сайта, Основы форматирования и т. д.

Comment: @Aer забыл отписаться. Должны были все исправить.

Comment: Я просматривал, вроде все исправлено. Спасибо. Я также подал заявку в Transifex, чтобы предлагать изменения напрямую. Кстати, не подскажете, а можно ли этимологов и запятую из описания сайта убрать вообще везде, а не только в Туре?

Comment: @Aer Думаю, что да, можно. Единственная проблема – строки могут быть разрозненны, а кое где и жестко заданы в коде или настройках сайта, которые доступны только разработчикам.